# Take out text in pairs of brackets out of string

Tags: python, string

Is it possible to take out text in pairs of brackets out of a string into a list, with the non-bracketed text in another list, with both lists being nested in the same list? This is what I mean:

`"hello{ok}why{uhh}so"` --> `[["hello","why","so"],["ok","uhh"]]`

Comment: How about this: `x = "hello{ok}why{uhh}so".replace('{', ',').replace('}', ',').split(','); out = [x[::2], x[1::2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the sample you shared, this is quite easy with `re` modules. However, if your text is huge, you will have to think about improvising this solution. Using re, you can do something like below

```
import re
raw_text = "hello{ok}why{uhh}so"
result = [re.split(r"{[A-Za-z]*}", raw_text),re.findall(r"{([A-Za-z]*)}",raw_text)]
print(result)
```

produces a result

```
[['hello', 'why', 'so'], ['ok', 'uhh']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code may help you

```
input_str = "hello{ok}why{uhh}so"
list1, parsed_parentheses = [], []

for index in range(len(input_str)):
    if input_str[index] == "{":
        parsed_parentheses.append(input_str[index])
        substr = ""
        continue
    else:
        if parsed_parentheses == []:
            continue
        if input_str[index] == "}":
            parsed_parentheses.append(input_str[index])
            list1.append(substr)
        if "{" == parsed_parentheses[-1]:
            substr += input_str[index]

input_str = input_str.replace("{", "-").replace('}', "-").split('-')
list2 = list(set(input_str) - set(list1))
result = [list2, list1]
```

It produces the following result

```
[['hello', 'why', 'so'], ['ok', 'uhh']]
```